# Pinch zoom to view all icons of GridView in android

Tags: android

I have implemented a launcher application based on grid view with flipper to show all the application icons successfully. Using flipper I am able to view all pages one by one.

I want to implement pinch zoom (multi touch) to view all the pages in single page (Refer default launcher in android). And by clicking a mini page in that, it should open the respective page.

Please guide me for the above problem.

Thanks,
Biplab